# Disable the queries to root DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm facing the same issue as reported in the below link. I have a DNS server running on 192.168.1.3 and it's in the forwarders list of named.conf. But when I try to query a hostname which is not configured either in /etc/hosts and DNS server, I see that lot of queries are being made to the root DNS servers. I want to disable the queries being sent to root DNS servers. I had tried all the suggestions provided in the link below but i still see the queries to the root DNS server.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875168/disabling-root-dns-server-queries-on-redhat-linux

Also, replaced the "forward first" option to "forward only" in /etc/named.conf. With this, the failure responses are not seen but the root server is queried.

Please suggest a way to disable the queries to root DNS servers.

Comment: To clarify: 192.168.1.3 is the same machine you are working on, or a DNS server in your network?

Comment: Not sure about *nix, but on Windows, if the file that has the root servers is populated (cache.dns), it will be used. Maybe you could try removing the entries (/var/named/root.hints ?)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to disable DNS recursion in BIND - this way any zones that the DNS server does not have an answer to locally will return with an 'NXDOMAIN'

To disable DNS recursion in named, you should set the following in your `named.conf` configuration file:

```
recursion no;
```